# Pip issues after 12.02->14.04 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7, pip

With Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, many but not all pip commands fail as so:

```
# sudo pip install --upgrade distribute
Downloading/unpacking distribute
  Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145kB): 145kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking setuptools>=0.7 (from distribute)

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py",
  line 1259, in prepare_files
    )[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Switching to not use wheel gets me past this:

```
sudo pip install --no-use-wheel --upgrade distribute
```

But I have scripts that I don't control that need pip to work.  What could be up?
Any time a ".whl" or "wheel" file is involved, it seems to choke.  Any clues to a true fix?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1375357